# Access multidimensional arrays in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, arrays, json, multidimensional-array, speech-recognition

I have JSON from the Google Speech API. I made this an array by using `NSArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: jsonResponse options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &e];`

Now, my array looks like this (dumped using `NSLog(@"%@",jsonArray)` ):

```
{
    result =     (
                {
            alternative =             (
                                {
                    confidence = "0.88664246";
                    transcript = test;
                },
                                {
                    transcript = tests;
                },
                                {
                    transcript = teste;
                },
                                {
                    transcript = pest;
                },
                                {
                    transcript = Test;
                }
            );
            final = 1;
        }
    );
    "result_index" = 0;
}
```

I need to access the first object, or this part:

```
transcript = "test";
```

How could I access this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would say:

```
NSLog(@"%@", jsonArray[@"result"][0][@"alternative"][0][@"transcript"]);
```

Please note that the root object is a dictionary, not an array.

I have a feeling you will need a more generic way of accessing it, so consider creating local objects (perhaps CoreData objects) that represent the objects in the JSON schema, so you can instantiate them and access them normally, instead of by traversing arrays and dictionaries.

Comment: Thank you for answering! This does not work though, it errors out with the following error: `Expected method to read dictionary element not found on object of type 'NSArray *'`

Comment: @awesomebing1, that's because, as jeffamaphone already mentioned, `jsonArray` is not an array. It is a dictionary. Change its type to `NSDictionary *`.